# Changing author name of user post on Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

The application I'm developing is really similar to Instagram.

On Instagram, users can change their usernames anytime. And if you change your username, your posts also show the updated username.

How can I implement this on a firebase database environment?

For example, I have VO below.

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Post {

    String uid;
    String username;
    String content;
    int likesCount = 0;
    Map<String, Boolean> likes = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Boolean> hashtags = new HashMap<>();

    public Post() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
    }

    public Post(String uid, String username, String content) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("uid", uid);
        result.put("username", username);
        result.put("content", content);
        result.put("likesCount", likesCount);
        result.put("likes", likes);
        result.put("hashtags", hashtags);

        return result;
    }
}
```

1. If I include "username" in the Post Object, I can show each post with the usernames synchronously, but it will be difficult to show the latest updated "username" all the time.

   If one user's Posts are over 1000, should I update all the posts at the same time when the username is changed?
2. If I exclude "username" in Post object I can load updated "username" asynchronously each time after any Post is loaded.
3. Or at the first time just show old username, and check if it is changed everytime when the Post is loaded, and update it asynchronously.

Which is the most efficient and proper way to implement for it?

Comment: How is an user's info stored in the database? Post the JSON structure as text. You can get this by clicking the Export JSON link in Firebase console.

Comment: @RamithDR Sorry for late response. It's still rough. {
  "users" : {
    "6rFrdBjiXtSwKz2NZsAjrARFwcu2" : {
      "id" : "evergreen",
      "username" : "Tom"
    }
  }
}